# How to add extremely large numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have numbers in SQL Server that stored in string format

These values are in 0 and 1s only

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '100101001010100111010001010101011101010110100001010010111001'
declare @b varchar(max) = '010101100101010010101101001010100010100011010000101000100010'
```

a and b length can reach 100,000 digits

I want to add these 2 variables as numeric

Something like

```
@a + @b
```

And the result should be

```
 110202101111110121111102011111111111110121110001111010211011
```

You can see this is not a binary adding... there are 2s

How can I do this in SQL Server?

I tried this

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '100101001010100111010001010101011101010110100001010010111001'
declare @b varchar(max) = '010101100101010010101101001010100010100011010000101000100010'

declare @ai bigint = cast(@a as bigint)
declare @bi bigint = cast(@b as bigint)

SELECT @ai + @bi
```

but I got this error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

How can I do that?

Comment: are these binary strings? if so why not store it as a more compact form?

Comment: i don't think any sql implementation can handle that for you

Comment: if it is within 38 digits, you can use Decimal.

Comment: you have to loop through, perhaps in groups of 64 bits (63), converting each to bigints, adding them, and then converting and concatenating into a a new string. Recursive CTE could do but upto 1600 iterations for long values would make it somewhat slow, if you have lots of rows to process, do you?

Comment: You could break this into suitable sized chunks, add them as bigints, then put them back together.

Comment: I'm curious about the use case here. Where does the data come from and where is it going? Is there only two terms? Will the result always only contain 0,1,2?

Comment: This seems like a bad use for a relational database. But if it absolutely needs doing, consider implementing [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) as a CLR data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create your own calculator.

Some complicating factors, that the code below takes into consideration:

- losing leading zeroes when converting number to string
- carry over most significant digit from one batch to the next in case of overflow

For example:

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '100101001010100111010001010101011101010110100001010010311001'
declare @b varchar(max) = '010101100101010010101101001010100010100011010000101000900010'
declare @e varchar(max) = '110202101111110121111102011111111111110121110001111011211011'  -- expected

declare @r varchar(max) = ''  -- result

declare @batch_size int  -- amount of digits to process at once
set @batch_size=18
declare @sum varchar(19)  -- must be bigger than @batch_size
declare @carry bigint
set @carry = 0

declare @length int
set @length = LEN(@a)  -- assumes LEN(@a) = LEN(@b)

declare @i int
set @i = @length / @batch_size
if @length % @batch_size = 0
  set @i = @i - 1

while @i >= 0 begin
  if @i * @batch_size + @batch_size > @length begin
    set @a = @a + REPLICATE('0', @batch_size - @length % @batch_size)
    set @b = @b + REPLICATE('0', @batch_size - @length % @batch_size)
  end
  
  set @sum = CAST(SUBSTRING(@a, @i * @batch_size + 1, @batch_size) AS bigint)
           + CAST(SUBSTRING(@b, @i * @batch_size + 1, @batch_size) AS bigint)
           + @carry

  set @carry = 0
  if LEN(@sum) > @batch_size begin
    set @carry = SUBSTRING(@sum, 1, 1)
    set @sum = SUBSTRING(@sum, 2, @batch_size)
  end
  
  if LEN(@sum) < @batch_size
    set @sum = REPLICATE('0', @batch_size - LEN(@sum)) + @sum
  
  if @i * @batch_size + @batch_size > @length
    set @sum = SUBSTRING(@sum, 1, @length - @i * @batch_size)
  
  set @r = @sum + @r
  
  set @i = @i - 1
end

if @carry > 0
  print 'overflow error'

if @r <> @e
  print 'not the correct result'

select substring(@r,1,@length) as sum_of_a_and_b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FLOAT(53):

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '100101001010100111010001010101011101010110100001010010111001'
declare @b varchar(max) = '010101100101010010101101001010100010100011010000101000100010'

declare @ai FLOAT(53) = cast(@a as FLOAT(53))
declare @bi FLOAT(53) = cast(@b as FLOAT(53))
```

The result of `SELECT @ai + @b` will be 1.1020210111111E+59
This will work for your sample input. But 100.000 digits will be impossible as numeric data type.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=283aac2fec2b0926f6c3da5d0797c43e)

Comment: i don't think that will store 100000 digits

Comment: No, that's not was SQL is done for ;)

Comment: the sample i provided because i wont put 100k digits in the example, but in my table there will be 100k digits.

Comment: Yes, I understood. As I said, I think this is impossible in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As your input digits are restricted to `1` and `0` you can do the following.

First create a numbers table with at least as many rows in it as your longest string.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW));

INSERT dbo.Numbers
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2
```

And then you can do

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '100101001010100111010001010101011101010110100001010010111001'
declare @b varchar(max) =  '10101100101010010101101001010100010100011010000101000100010'
declare @c varchar(max) 

SELECT @c = STRING_AGG(0 + SUBSTRING(normalised.a, Number, 1) + SUBSTRING(normalised.B, Number, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Number)
FROM dbo.Numbers
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEN(@a), LEN(@b)) lengths(len_a, len_b)
/*If @a and @b are not equal length add zeroes to left pad out the shorter one*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', len_b-len_a),@a), CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', len_a-len_b),@b)) normalised(a,b)
WHERE Number <= LEN(normalised.a)

PRINT @c
```